# Can't delete folder after failed git clone

Tags: git, windows-7, cygwin

I'm trying to clone a git repo. I'm using cygwin on a windows 7 OS. Somehow, it fails, but create a folder. When I try to delete it, got this message:

> rmdir: fallo al borrar «myRepoName/»: Device or resource busy

I can't delete it even using the windows explorer.

¿What does it means this message, and how can I delete these folders?

Comment: I've tried to uumount the dir (umount myRepoName) and I've got an " Invalid argument" error. I've also tried to run regedit and change the native key, as is referred in http://srv.onzk.net/linwin/apache-php3-mysql/CygWin_20b_98-4_Documents_OnLine/CygWin-Faq/faq_4.html, but the key doesn't exists at all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that no shells, Windows explorer windows or applications are open to anything in the git subtree and try again.  Next, close all your apps and try again.  If that doesn't work, reboot and try again.  Windows is overly protective of open files and directories, and some apps don't close them properly.

Comment: Restart worked when everything else failed, then could delete. For me, specifically it was a pip folder under appdata containing a tree, involving Cython, however I suspect this might have also been the reason some pip install commands were producing unexpected errors.

Comment: Glad that worked - I've had many similar frustrating things with Win-based OSes.  Linux Is much more forgiving, as it's architected to handle move / rename / delete with open / busy files and directories... Thanks for accepting the answer!

Comment: For me it we the fact that I had ran a command with '--help' which opened a HTML help file, which although wasn't located in the same git directory, it was preventing me from removing the directory. Close the browser window/tab - problem solved

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a bit old but hopefully this helps someone else who experiences this issue.

I found that, in Windows 10 at least, using the task manager to stop all git processes is enough to free up the files so they can be removed. Then simply restart git and you are good to go. No reboot required.

Comment: I killed `git` and `bash` processes in Task Manager and I still get `rm: cannot remove 'learning-git': Device or resource busy`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAlUW.png Had the same problem. After closing all the 'git for Windows' processes I was able to remove the directory. (Win 10 Pro, git version 2.10.1.windows.1)

Comment: Worked in Win7 for me as well.

Comment: This worked for me.
I did two things --
1. stopped git-credentials-manager.exe using task manager
2. closed all open cmd, git bash, github desktop, etc.

After that, when I opened windows explorer, went to the .git folder and deleted the required file, it was deleted. I also was successful deleting .git folder using the same method.

Comment: I use TortoiseGit, so I had to kill the TGit status cache process too.

Comment: At window 10 task manager, I did end task to Git  for Windows. It works.

Answer (score 1):

If you were working with NodeJS then the below should resolve it without restarting your PC:

cntr + alt + delete -> task manager -> processes -> find all Node.js: Server-side Javascript under Name tab -> right-click and select 'end task' for all of those instances.
[Screenshot: you're looking to kill these tasks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvM2k.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
I stopped the bash process in task manager. I then removed each file one by one until I could delete the whole folder.